# Akka HTTP route post entity string, complete with Future

Tags: scala, routes, akka, future, akka-http

I have an Akka HTTP daemon. Assume that I want to receive some client data in JSON format and save it into a database asynchronously. I wrote a route in a POST branch:

```
path("product") {
  entity(as[String]) { json =>
    val saveFuture: Future[Unit] = Serialization.read[Product](json).save()
    complete("")
  }
}
```

I've found that `complete` can be put into an `onSuccess` statement like:

```
path("success") {
  onSuccess(Future { "Ok" }) { extraction =>
    complete(extraction)
  }
}
```

But I can't understand how to glue them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest the directives:

```
path("product") {
  entity(as[String]) { json =>
    val saveFuture: Future[Unit] = Serialization.read[Product](json).save()
    onSuccess(saveFuture) {
      complete("json was saved")
    }
  }
}
```